Wrong Network shown for claiming Param tokens
I have to claim my param tokens but once I connect the metamask wallet it shows wrong Network (Arbitrium) in paramgaming website. I have selected different network in my wallet and have reconnected wallet several times but still same.

Make sure only the one web wallet active in browser. Select the account that's blocking and disconnect from the site in metamask. Hit the icon left of the url address bar in the browser, remove any cookies and site data then hard refresh with Control-Shift-R. Select to connect while the right account shows in metamask.
